# Share connection pool among servlets

Tags: java, servlets, connection-pooling

I'd like to share a database connection among servlets.

I created the connection pool and I obtain the dataSource object like this

```
Context envContext  = (Context)context.lookup("java:/comp/env");
dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/limedb");
```

Now, I'd like to share this dataSource object among servlet so that each servlet can just do

```
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

to get its own connection.

What is the best method to achieve this? I'd like to create the pool at the application startup and store it somewhere...

Comment: ... why pool if the servlets need to share the exact same connection? and are you -really- sure that this is what you want? That seems like a concurrency hell in the making.

Comment: How to make them share the same connection then?

Comment: I believe there's a major misunderstanding. The pool is already created and stored during application's startup! With `context.lookup()` you're just obtaining a reference to it ... A cleaner way is using `@Resource`.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few ways you can do this.

1. You can use a dependency injection framework to manage those
   connections for you. Behind the scenes it will use an object pool.
2. You can create a singleton object that manages an object pool containing datasources for you.
3. You can write a singleton containing the code that returns the connection for you, so you don't have to know you are using a datasource.

It all depends on the use case, how familiar you are with java, the overall design of your application, etc.